# Translate += in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any easy way where we can add += for CSS.

```js
var obj = $('#svg > g');
var x = parseInt(obj.attr('transform').split(/[()]/)[1].split(',')[0]);
var y = parseInt(obj.attr('transform').split(/[()]/)[1].split(',')[1]);
obj.attr('transform', 'translate(' + (x + 100) + ', ' + (y + 5) + ')');
$('#svg').css("width", "+=200");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="200">
    <g transform="translate(10, 10)">
   <rect x="0" y="0" rx="10" ry="10" width="100%" height="100%" pointer-events="all"></rect>
  </g>
 </svg>
```

Similar to styling the width. //**css("width", "+=200");**

i need for transform translate something like **obj.attr('transform', 'translateX("+="'+100+')');**.

Comment: `parseInt` should be used with a second parameter set to `10`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jquery width attribute:

```
$('#svg').width($('#svg').width() + 200);
```

For the transforming the attribute, you can get the position

```
var x = $('#svg > g').position().left;
var y = $('#svg > g').position().top;
```

Then throw that to change the CSS of the object

```
$('#svg g').css({'transform': 'translate(' +  (x + 100) +'px, ' + (y + 5) + 'px'});
```

Comment: Thanks Josh. For width i could increase easily by +=. I need similar kind of flow for transform translate style.

Comment: Hey Vijay, I've edited my answer to include the transform translating, hope that helps!